# Google Play Console crash reporting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android

I get a crash report on the Google Play Console on this device: Samsung Galaxy A5(2016) (a5xelte),

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: 

  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray (Native Method)

  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset (Native Method)

  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream (BitmapFactory.java:700)

  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream (BitmapFactory.java:535)

  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream (Drawable.java:1179)

  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie (ResourcesImpl.java:770)

  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable (ResourcesImpl.java:621)

  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:1729)

  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable (TypedArray.java:945)

  at android.widget.ImageView.<init> (ImageView.java:157)

  at android.widget.ImageView.<init> (ImageView.java:145)

  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init> (AppCompatImageView.java:60)

  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init> (AppCompatImageView.java:56)

  at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:98)

  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView (AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:926)

  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView (AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:980)

  at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView (LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView (LayoutInflater.java:193)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:776)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:734)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:865)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:828)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:873)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:828)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:873)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:828)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:873)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:828)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:525)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:427)

  at package.Accueil.onCreateView (Accueil.java:75)

  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:1965)

  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1078)

  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1259)

  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run (BackStackRecord.java:738)

  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java:1624)

  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions (FragmentController.java:330)

  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java:547)

  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1256)

  at android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:6972)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2937)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3045)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14 (ActivityThread.java)

  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1642)

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)

  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1496)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

The crash line :
**at package.Accueil.onCreateView (Accueil.java:75)**

Is this one:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar_title);
```

I don't understand how the app can crash on this line. I did search on Google they talk about big file to load...

Here is all of my drawables:

[image]

The view:

[image]

I think the problem is with my drawables and the density of the images, I don't rteally understand this: I did a question about:

[Understanding Drawables and Images sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48702157/understanding-drawables-and-images-sizes/48702240#48702240)

I don't know if I have all screen sizes.

Comment: have u set any bg image in text view in xml?

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError` is not possible with this line of code . Double check your production code and confirm the line number .

Comment: @duggu I have many images on this activity and big size images too

Comment: then this is main problem

Comment: @ADM Ok Google Play Console showed this line (75) and the line is the TextView, how to know where it crashes

Comment: Do not set images directly in `XML` load them handling possible `exception` use some good library which handles `OutOfMemory` for example `Glide` or `Picasso`

Answer (score 1):

OOME comes while instantiating your layout  (especially images) -  maybe there is some bad bitmap which is too big? Maybe your layout is too complex?

Comment: Why the error is on this devices ? Can I simulate it with a virtual device ? I have many images, this is the image size or the weight ?

Comment: Could be a lot of cauese -   device has less memory  than others,  device uses  one version of resource  (because of screen resolution or whatever )which is buggy..... As for simulating on virtual device - it willl be difficult  to recreate particular phone.   Maybe you can get real one and debug?

Comment: So I can't know where it came from ? Can I do something ? Like pass images on tinypng to compress images ?

Comment: It is definitely some image.  Hard to telll which.   DO you have dieeferent assets for different resolutions etc?

Comment: Impossible to tell what exact cause is.

Comment: I think I have all drawables folders... But I don't know if I put the right dimensions..

Comment: Obviously, some of these images  are just too big.    While they are compressed in apk,   they are converted to raster images  which consume some bytes per pixel ( depending on color space etc ) -   so reduce resolution,  adjust color space and maybe problem will go away.

Comment: Okay but here is a problem I don't know how to adjust images resolutions for each drawables

Answer (score 1):

OOM is not usually related to one place. Even though the crash is at at package.Accueil.onCreateView (Accueil.java:75) most likely it's not caused by that. IN my experience the OOM are caused by bigger images than needed.

If you are downloading images from some server use Glide to fetch it because it will keep in memory only the resized image that fits your view even if the actual image was way bigger before resize.
Check this comparison between Glide and Picasso: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

You might also check for memory leaks using LeakCanary but I would first start with images.

Comment: Okay so I did an edit with the view, I don't have a lot of big images on, but I think the problem is with the drawables..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is when this line is executed, the platform creates your View heirarchy. You presumably have lots of big images in your view, so your App has to allocate a lot of memory to display all these big images. So now the solution comes down to how do you fix things. You have two options:

- Have a design with fewer or smaller images
- Make your images use less memory

I'd advise doing both. I can't advise you on improving the design. But for reducing sizes, [this section in the documentation is a good guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/network-xfer.html). It is talking about network transfer, but will probably help in your APK too.

[There is also some good advice here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/index.html).

Comment: Okay so I did an edit with the view, I don't have a lot of big images on, but I think the problem is with the drawables..