# Understanding Drawables and Images sizes

Tags: android, drawable

Firstly I did a lot of search to understand how it work, but I don't find simples tutorials. An exemple, this view:

[image]

These are my drawables folders:

[image]

The selected device is: Pixel 5.0 1080 x 1920 (xxhdpi).

Immagine in this resolution (1080 x 1920) I set the image view on the top in blue color (Solutis) with 700px of width and 250 px of height, how I have to resize this images for each drawables folders ?

I found this informations:

```
LDPI - 0.75x
MDPI - Original size // means 1.0x here 
HDPI - 1.5x
XHDPI - 2.0x
XXHDPI - 3x
XXXHDPI - 4.0x
```

And

```
LDPI: Portrait: 200 X 320px
MDPI: Portrait: 320 X 480px
HDPI: Portrait: 480 X 800px
XHDPI: Portrait: 720 X 1280px
XXHDPI: Portrait: 960 X 1600px
XXXHDPI: Portrait: 1440 x 2560px
```

Here I don't understand why when I select my vistuel device 1080 x 1920px on the Design Edit it say xxhdpi and xxhdpi is 960 X 1600px...

And what gonna be the different sizes of the image for the differents drawables ?

If someone can publish a project exemple, I wool look on, please.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)? Here is the interesting part:

> #### Density-independent pixel (dp)
>
> A virtual pixel unit that you should use when defining UI layout, to express layout dimensions or position in a density-independent way.
>
> The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen, which is the baseline density assumed by the system for a "medium" density screen. At runtime, the system transparently handles any scaling of the dp units, as necessary, based on the actual density of the screen in use. The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi / 160). For example, on a 240 dpi screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels. You should always use dp units when defining your application's UI, to ensure proper display of your UI on screens with different densities.

This means if your device as a higher density a bigger image will been chosen.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand, here is different 0.75 - ldpi 1.0 - mdpi 1.5 - hdpi 2.0 - xhdpi 3.0 - xxhdpi 4.0 - xxxhdpi, okay so the devices gonna automatically select the drawable, but my question is how I would set the size of an image for each drawables?

Comment: Those numbers are multiplyer. Maybe my calculator can enlighten you: http://www.rekisoft.eu/tools/dp-calculator.html

Comment: So for exemple for a image of 200*400 in mdpi, gonna be 400*800 for xhdpi ?

Comment: And I don't understand why we can select dp or px ?

Comment: That's right. Basically this is for having crisp images instead of blurred images depending on your density of your device.

Comment: So we have to do different images in different dp and different px ? How many folders of drawables for all things ??

Comment: And how we can go crisp and blurred images ??

Comment: All equal named pictures should have the same dp resolution and depending on the folder (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi) the same dp size, but other px size. If you need to upscale an image e.g. you did not provide the image, then the system will upscale the image and since the image has less pixels then required the image will get blurry. Nower days hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi should be enough.

Comment: Okay do you have a project with a set of images for exemple please ?

Comment: Well I have here a very old example app: https://github.com/rekire/EditMail/tree/master/SampleApp/src/main/res

Comment: I just found the icone launcher, what about a picture we would add in a view of the app ?

Comment: The rules (scale factors) for the sizes are always the same, it really depends on the design you want. In general try using a 8dp grid as general recommendation.